# Changing templates for packs

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Given

```
template <typename...> class P;  template <typename...> class Q;
template <typename...> class R;  template <typename...> class S;
```

Let us define, `change_templates` as in the following example:

```
change_templates<P<int, char, R<double, int>, bool>, P,Q, R,S>::type
```

is to be

```
Q<int, char, S<double, int>, bool>
```

And more generally,

```
change_templates<P<int, Q<int, int>, char, P<double, P<char, char>, int>, bool>, P,Q, P,R, Q,S>::type
```

is to be

```
Q<int, S<int, int>, char, R<double, P<char, char>, int>, bool>
```

(note that the lack of a third `P,...` pair means that the third P is to remain unchanged, though `P,P` could be used instead anyway).  The good news is that I have it working with the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename...> class...> struct TP;

template <template <typename...> class, typename Templates, typename Checked = TP<>> struct find_template;

template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class Q,
    template <typename...> class... Rest, template <typename...> class... Checked>
struct find_template<P, TP<Q, Rest...>, TP<Checked...>> :
    find_template<P, TP<Rest...>, TP<Checked..., Q>> {};  // Search the next template by default.

template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class Q,
    template <typename...> class... Rest, template <typename...> class... Checked>
struct find_template<P, TP<P, Q, Rest...>, TP<Checked...>> {  // Q follows P, which means that P is to change to Q.
    template <typename... Ts>
    using type = Q<Ts...>;
    using remaining_templates = TP<Checked..., Rest...>;  // Every template except P,Q kept for later searches, since they have been used now.
};

template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Checked>
struct find_template<P, TP<>, TP<Checked...>> {  // P not found.
    template <typename... Ts>
    using type = P<Ts...>;  // P not found, so simply don't change P.
    using remaining_templates = TP<Checked...>;
};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class... Templates>
struct change_templates {
    using type = T;  // Base case.  A non-pack type remains unchanged.
};

template <typename T, typename Templates> struct change_templates_impl;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class... Templates>
struct change_templates_impl<T, TP<Templates...>> :
    change_templates<T, Templates...> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class... Templates>
struct change_templates<P<Ts...>, Templates...> {  // A pack of types (possibly of other packs).
    using F = find_template<P, TP<Templates...>>;
    using Remaining = typename F::remaining_templates;  // To be passed on for the next find_template call.
    using type = typename F::template type<typename change_templates_impl<Ts, Remaining>::type...>;  // Recursive call.
};

// Testing
template <typename...> class P;  template <typename...> class Q;
template <typename...> class R;  template <typename...> class S;

int main() {
    static_assert (std::is_same<change_templates<P<int, char, double>, P, Q>::type, Q<int, char, double>>::value, "");

    static_assert (std::is_same<
        change_templates<P<int, char, R<double, int>, bool>, P,Q, R,S>::type,
        Q<int, char, S<double, int>, bool>
    >::value, "");

    static_assert (std::is_same<
        change_templates<P<int, Q<int, int>, char, P<double, P<char, char>, int>, bool>, P,Q, P,R, Q,S>::type,  // The third P in the pack is unchanged because there is no pair for the third P.
        Q<int, S<int, int>, char, R<double, P<char, char>, int>, bool>
    >::value, "");
}
```

But now I naturally want the following:

```
template <int...> class I;  template <int...> class J;

int main() {
    static_assert (std::is_same<
        change_templates<P<int, char, I<4,5>, bool>, P,Q, I,J>::type,
        Q<int, char, J<4,5>, bool>
    >::value, "");
}
```

But I don't know how to adapt my above code to handle this, because P,Q, are templates of types, while I,J are templates of int (or more generally of any integral type).  Is there someway to homogenize the different types of templates so that the above will work as intended (or with a slightly different syntax)?  And what if we have both packs of `int` and packs of `std::size_t`, etc...in the same pack?

Comment: I couldn't hold myself not to say that "this code looks horribly unmaintainable"

Comment: Could you use the type `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 4>` int of `4` as workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is semi-satisfactory for me.  At least all different kinds of templates are now homogenized into types, and that specific static assertion is now satisfied.  If someone can just guide me on how to generalize the `int` in the last partial specialization of `change_templates`, it may remove the "unmaintainable" aspect of the solution remarked by Murat Karakus.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <template <typename...> class...> struct K;
template <typename T, template <T...> class...> struct L;

template <typename Find, typename Templates, typename Checked = std::tuple<>> struct find_template;

template <typename FindMe, template <typename...> class Z, typename Mismatch, typename... Rest, typename... Checked>
struct find_template<FindMe, Z<Mismatch, Rest...>, Z<Checked...>> : find_template<FindMe, Z<Rest...>, Z<Checked..., Mismatch>> {};  // Search the next template by default.

template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class Z, template <typename...> class Q, typename... Rest, typename... Checked>
struct find_template<K<P>, Z<K<P,Q>, Rest...>, Z<Checked...>> {  // Q follows P, which means that P is to change to Q.
    template <typename... Ts>
    using type = Q<Ts...>;
    using remaining_templates = Z<Checked..., Rest...>;  // Every template except P,Q kept for later searches, since they have been used now.
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, template <typename...> class Z, template <T...> class Q, typename... Rest, typename... Checked>
struct find_template<L<T,P>, Z<L<T,P,Q>, Rest...>, Z<Checked...>> {  // Q follows P, which means that P is to change to Q.
    template <T... Is>
    using type = Q<Is...>;
    using remaining_templates = Z<Checked..., Rest...>;  // Every template except P,Q kept for later searches, since they have been used now.
};

template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class Z, typename... Checked>
struct find_template<K<P>, Z<>, Z<Checked...>> {  // P not found.
    template <typename... Ts>
    using type = P<Ts...>;  // P not found, so simply don't change P.
    using remaining_templates = Z<Checked...>;
};

template <typename T, typename... Templates>
struct change_templates {
    using type = T;  // Base case.  A non-pack type remains unchanged.
};

template <typename T, typename Templates> struct change_templates_impl;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class Z, typename... Templates>
struct change_templates_impl<T, Z<Templates...>> : change_templates<T, Templates...> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Templates>
struct change_templates<P<Ts...>, Templates...> {  // A pack of types (possibly of other packs).
    using F = find_template<K<P>, std::tuple<Templates...>>;
    using Remaining = typename F::remaining_templates;  // To be passed on for the next find_template call.
    using type = typename F::template type<typename change_templates_impl<Ts, Remaining>::type...>;  // Recursive call.
};

template <template <int...> class P, int... Is, typename... Templates>
struct change_templates<P<Is...>, Templates...> {  // A pack of integral non-types.
    using F = find_template<L<int,P>, std::tuple<Templates...>>;
    using type = typename F::template type<Is...>;  // Non-recursive call, since the Is... cannot themselves be packs.
};

// Testing
template <typename...> class P;  template <typename...> class Q;
template <typename...> class R;  template <typename...> class S;
template <int...> class I;  template <int...> class J;

int main() {
    static_assert (std::is_same<change_templates<P<int, char, double>, K<P,Q>>::type, Q<int, char, double>>::value, "");

    static_assert (std::is_same<
        change_templates<P<int, char, R<double, int>, bool>, K<P,Q>, K<R,S>>::type,
        Q<int, char, S<double, int>, bool>
    >::value, "");

    static_assert (std::is_same<
        change_templates<P<int, Q<int, int>, char, P<double, P<char, char>, int>, bool>, K<P,Q>, K<P,R>, K<Q,S>>::type,  // The third P in the pack is unchanged because there is no K pair for the third P.
        Q<int, S<int, int>, char, R<double, P<char, char>, int>, bool>
    >::value, "");

    static_assert (std::is_same<
        change_templates<P<int, char, I<4,5>, bool>, K<P,Q>, L<int,I,J>>::type,
        Q<int, char, J<4,5>, bool>
    >::value, "");
}
```

Update:  I realize that generalizing the int cannot be done, anymore than any compiler can deduce `T` from the function

```
template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T... Is>
T foo(P<Is...>);
```

So

```
template <template <int...> class P, int... Is, typename... Templates>
struct change_templates<P<Is...>, Templates...>
```

needs to be repeated for the other integral types.